# How can I add a high resolution device to Responsive Design Mode?

Tags: firefox, responsive-design, firefox-developer-tools

I've added an iPhone X to Firefox Responsive Design Mode:

[image]

This is [the correct resolution, and Device Pixel Ratio for an iPhone X](https://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-x/specs/):

> 2436x1125-pixel resolution at 458 ppi

However when using the custom device, Firefox shows the device to be massive. It seems to ignore the DPR on the device completely.

[image]

**How can I add a high resolution device to Responsive Design Mode?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody else has answered, and I've found something myself:

**Divide the real pixel size by the DPR and enter that as the 'Size'**.

- 1125 / 3
- 2436 / 3

So for an iPhone X, if you want to cut and paste, you'd enter:

- `375`
- `812`
- `3`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A356 Safari/604.1`

This is odd, as you've already entered the DPR and would expect Firefox to calculate this for you, but that's how it works.

[image]